# missing pictures on page [facebook]

Tags: php, html, facebook, image

To address this issue, I've opened a call (well, several calls, actually) with the facebook support team but never got a logical answer.

The issue is simple : pictures disappear from a facebook page after some time.

The problem is on one page, that is [Discovery Publisher](https://www.facebook.com/DiscoveryPublisher). Towards the bottom of the page (i.e. esp. dated 2013 and before), some of the pictures don’t display anymore. They displayed fine after upload, but stopped being displayed after a while.

We created these posts. Each picture was uploaded individually from a personal computer.

An initial investigation shows that these pictures are located on one of facebook's servers (see screenshots below). So we logged a call with the support team. Their conclusion is that the issue resides on our side, i.e. on our website.

This does not seem to be the case, however, and that because (1) it worked before and in between we did not change anything; (2) the original pictures were never located on our serveur; and (3) the initial investigation reveals that the pictures are actually stored on one of facebook's servers, and not on our website.

Specifically, for instance, if we take the case of this post, which isn’t displayed on facebook anymore:

[image: missing picture on facebook]

The link of the post is [here](http://www.discoverypublisher.com/publication/james-hilton-lost-horizon/), which is working fine.

The picture loaded at the time was this one:

[image: original picture on facebook]

Which was loaded from a computer and not pulled from our website.

According to the screenshot below, the image is located on one of facebook's servers:

[image: code shows the broken link on server side]

which is [here](https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/v/t1.0-9/10959845_933683489975271_7056043458274581542_n.jpg) but triggers the following error on a browser: "An error occurred while processing your request. Reference #50.3c0edd58.1448968164.3378a460"

However, if I now do the same with an image that is displayed correctly on our facebook page:

[image: working picture on facebook]

The image URL, according to this screenshot:

[image: picture link not broken on facebook server side]

is [this one](https://fbcdn-creative-a.akamaihd.net/hads-ak-xta1/t45.1600-4/10736874_6024785256571_741407758_n.jpg), which displays just fine right now.

So, where is the issue, on our page, our server (i.e. discovery publisher), or on facebook's server?

---

Below is the answer given by facebook, can anyone make sense of it in this context?

Firstly, the url http://www.discoverypublisher.com/publication/james-hilton-lost-horizon/ does not contain any Open Graph tags. These are essential if your client wants the correct image, title, description to appear when they share on Facebook.
Please refer to the following links, Webmasters documentation [1](https://www.facebook.com/DiscoveryPublisher) and the URL debugger [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DB4m9.png) 
Here you will be able to see exactly what our crawler sees and what will display when your url is shared to Facebook. 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Images are cached asynchronously, so the image may not render the first time someone shares content. This sounds like the blank image problem that your are experiencing. This can be avoided by following the instructions in the caching images documentation [3](http://www.discoverypublisher.com/publication/james-hilton-lost-horizon/)
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/optimizing#cachingimages

---

Following, the call was closed, and any attempt to re-open it is immediately followed by a close call.

Comment: Maybe they migrate old pictures to other servers. Sounds logical to me as newer pictures have a higher chance of getting viewed. Maybe after three years they chance their location.

Comment: Where's facebooks answer?

Comment: Just added as part of the description.

Comment: I don't know man, I guess you should just follow that link they provided, or maybe you're just f*cked. Maybe in a couple of days it'll be fixed who knows.

Comment: It's been like this for months. Does anyone know how to get proper support from facebook, or how to escalate a call?

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the server responds telling you that

> An error occurred while processing your request.

and even gives you a unique code for it shows that it's a problem with the Facebook servers. It could be that the servers are (and have been) having problems over the last few weeks/days/hours, but as said in a comment, it's more likely a migration problem.